# jQuery carousel caption animation works fine in jsfiddle but not in brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In jsfiddle it shows exactly the same way as it is required but in brackets editor it shows animated carousel caption fadeInUp

[jsfiddle which is working the way i wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lwyc6rb/1/)

but when i try same code in brackets editor then it shows carousel caption fadeInUp instead of showing carousel caption from fadeInRight and carousel button from fadeInUp.

[check brackets editor here](http://127.0.0.1:51847/index.html)

```
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <!--first slide-->
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="image/stylegirl.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <div class="toggleCaption">
                <h1>Discounts upto 50% off</h1>

                <div class="toggleButton">
    <p><a class="btn btn-default-outline btn-lg" role="button"> Shop Now</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>


        <!--second slide-->
        <div class="item">
            <img src="image/couple.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <div class="toggleCaption">
                <h1>On Sale</h1>

                <div class="toggleButton">
      <p><a class="btn btn-default-outline btn-lg" role="button">Shop Now</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <!--Third Slide-->
        <div class="item">
            <img src="image/glamour.jpg" style="Width:100%">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <div class="toggleCaption">
                <h1>New Arrivals</h1>

                <div class="toggleButton">
      <p><a class="btn btn-default-outline btn-lg" role="button"> Shop Now</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</header>
```

Comment: The second link 'brackets editor' is broken. Did you test this directly in a browser?

Comment: yes in browser i tested it shows carousel caption fadeInUp as well as carousel button. whereas i wanted carousel caption from fadeInRight and carousel caption from fadeInUp